# C++ initialization in template function - new Initializer expression list treated as compound expression

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize widgets of different types in a template function. But I am getting an error "new Initializer expression list treated as compound expression".

```
template <class T>
void setProperties(T &widget, QString input)
{
    widget = new T(input, view());
}
```

Unfortunately couldn't find what is the error.

Comment: You are trying to assign a pointer to a reference. Do you really need a `new` here?

Comment: Please, give as a more reproducible example, not just function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your signature is wrong, it should be:

```
template <class T>
void setProperties(T*& widget, QString input)
{
    widget = new T(input, view());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new T(input, view())
```

gives you a pointer, but you are trying to assign it to a reference. Change your widget to be of type `T*& widget`.

Comment: I do need a pointer which i have already declared in the class. I want to initialize this pointer "widget" in this template function.

Comment: @user3714887 but `widget` is not a pointer, it's a reference. If it must be a pointer change the function signature from `T &widget` to `T* widget`.

Comment: Ya got it. silly mistake. Thank you!! please edit your answer ill accept it

Comment: `template <class T>
void setProperties(T*& widget, QString input);` ?

Comment: 'template <class T> void setProperties(T*& widget, QString input);'  works much better!!